# Microsoft .NET 3.5 Full download

Tags: .net, download, frameworks

Although not a question directly associated with programming. One does sometimes need certain frameworks in your projects.

I'm looking into downloading the .NET 3.5 framework [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21) but you end up downloading some 2MB installer that once you run it downloads the rest of the framework to your hard drive.

Where can I download the entire framework? The machine I'm downloading it for is not connected to the net so I want to download the frame work elsewhere and install on the offline machine.

Comment: *If only* there were a link, **ON THAT PAGE** that leads to the [full redistributable](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe). Oh, there is.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Oh therreeee it is, if you squint your eyes you can almost see it! :) Thanks man, my bad.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh crap... that's nice and hidden under an expando-thingy... thanks for pointing that out. Should throw up an answer that says "Look closer. It's there.". Shiny pictures help as well :)

Comment: @NobodyNada and the rest. Why did you close off this question? If you have no knowledge of the subject then please go entertain yourselves somewhere else. The OP is specifically asking how to download the full dot net framework installer. The OP did not ask anyone to recommend anything.

Comment: Yeah, and when you run it, it still tries to download things from the internet.  So this question is still extremely relevant.

Answer (score 26):

Direct link to the **.Net-3.5**-Full-Setup

> http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe

Direct link to the **.Net-3.5-SP1**-Full-Setup

> http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

Thanks to Dzmitry Lahoda!

Comment: [With SP1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe)